# Android AccountAuthenticator with multiple servers

Tags: java, android, accountmanager

I have developed an application which, apart from core functionality, connects to a server and  authenticates against it. Now, the requirements are changing and I'm trying to implement an application that is able to manage accounts for several possible instances of the same server that do not necessarily share data.

In short, a user needs to connect to ServerA with user@company.com and to ServerB with user@company.com. Obviously, account with `accountName` as user's e-mail and `accountType` as authenticator's identification string will not work because switching servers from A to B and back will invalidate the token because token for A will not work for B.

As such, I think there is a way I can think of but maybe someone can think of better solutions?

Application will provide server address as part of authenticator's options when adding an account:

```
String serverUrl = "...";
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(COMPANY_SERVER_URL, serverUrl);
am.getAccount(
    COMPANY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    COMPANY_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE,
    null,
    accountOptions,
    null,
    null
);
```

The authenticator will examine the provided options and propagate the URL to the activity. When account will be created, it will be created as following:

```
Account account = new Account(accountName + " at " + serverUrl, accountType);
Bundle userData = new Bundle();

userData.putString(COMPANY_SERVER_URL, serverUrl);
userData.putString(ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);

am.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, userData);
am.setAuthToken(account, authTokenType, token);
am.notifyAccountAuthenticated(account);
```

The idea is that account will now appear as `user@company.com at https://server-a.company.com/api` and `user@company.com at https://server-b.company.com/api`

The same process can be then applied to `getAuthToken`.

What do you think? Any suggestions? Should AccountManager not be used this way? How can I handle accounts for multiple server instances and later support sync?

Also, to clarify things, I do not know ahead of time what instances will be available so I cannot prepare authenticators for each server ahead of time. Basically, think of it as a server on your local LAN... there may be two or three, or you're going between locations that have these servers installed.

As an update, I noticed that AirBnB uses user's first and last names to identify an account. Potentially, two users may have the same name. Is there a way to manage account display labels?

So AirBnB actually fails as I expected. I guess their devs assume that two people with the same name will not use the same phone... which is probably a good assumption.

Comment: Did you make any headway with this?

Comment: Yeah, there was no support for managing the case I needed. As such, I only allowed one unique username. If it conflicted, I would warn and propose deletion.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I found the same in the end. Managed to get it working by appending the server name to the account name to ensure uniqueness. "darrell@test.com - Dev", "darrell@test.com - UAT" etc. I  also realised (in case it helps someone else) that as my authenticator apk is a seperate package to my app that calls accountmanager, both apks had to be signed with same key, otherwise things like getauthtoken wouldnt work